# How to count div of a specific class using PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a html string

```
html_string = '<div class="quote" post_id="48" 
style="border:1px solid #000;padding:15px;margin:15px;" user_id="1"
user_name="rashidfarooq">This is not True</div>

<div class="quote" post_id="49" style="border:1px 
solid #000;padding:15px;margin:15px;" user_id="1" 
user_name="rashidfarooq">This is good for me</div>

<div class="genuine" post_id="49" style="border:1px 
solid #000;padding:15px;margin:15px;" user_id="1" 
user_name="rashidfarooq">This is good for me</div>';
```

I want to count the div having class name = "quote"
I have tried

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html_string);
    $divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
    $length = $divs->length;
```

But the $length gives the total number of divs. How can I count only the divs having class name = "quote". Is there any PHP Native function that can do that.

Answer (score 2):

There doesnt seem to be a native domdocument function for that, but it's easy to write it yourself:

```
function getElementsByClassName($elements, $className) {
    $matches = array();
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        if (!$element->hasAttribute('class')) {
            continue;
        }
        $classes = preg_split('/\s+/', $element->getAttribute('class'));
        if ( ! in_array($className, $classes)) {
            continue;
        }
        $matches[] = $element;
    }
    return $matches;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$divs = getElementsByClassName($dom->getElementsByTagName('div'), 'quote');
$length = $divs->length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$DOMResponse = new \DOMDocument();
$DOMResponse->loadXML($data);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($DOMResponse);
$length = $xpath->query('/*[@class="quote"]')->length;
```

where `quote` is the class you want to query

## Note

If you also want to filter, before, for divs, you have to query for divs before and then apply query I'd suggested above

Something like this

```
$length = $xpath->query('//div[@class="quote"]')->length;
```