# How to count a specific class using PHP and display it's count on a page

Tags: php, wordpress, class, count

I have a wordpress driven website and running a plugin which allows me to proof my clients with photos from their photo-shoot. I am trying to add a simple section to show the selected images count at the top without messing with the plugin. I went to them first and they said it was a huge thing and wasn't implemented yet.

Having a php script to add into the display which would look at the document and count the number of classes labeled 'selected' and return a number.

I have a gallery online that you can see and get a feel for what I am trying to accomplish. I currently have 3 images selected to show you what I am aiming for, the title for selected is already there, I just need the php snippet.

http://www.drewjohnstonphotography.ca/proofgallery/crowell

The code I have below did not work either got it from [How to count div of a specific class using PHP DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654028/how-to-count-div-of-a-specific-class-using-php-domdocument) topic, just modified to show selected instead of quote, but this didn't work, unfortunately.

```
<div class="grid__item">
    <div class="entry__meta-box">
        <span class="meta-box__title"><h3>Selected</h3></span>
        <span>

<?php

function getElementsByClassName($elements, $className) {
$matches = array();
foreach($elements as $element) {
if (!$element->hasAttribute('class')) {
    continue;
}
$classes = preg_split('/\s+/', $element->getAttribute('class'));
if ( ! in_array($className, $classes)) {
    continue;
}
$matches[] = $element;
}
return $matches;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$divs = getElementsByClassName($dom->getElementsByTagName('div'), 'selected');
$length = $divs->length;

?>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use xpath? `//span[@class="meta-box__title"][contains(text(), 'Selected')]`?

Comment: Here is the exported html after the page has been built, I am looking to count just the classes titled 'selected'.

https://jsfiddle.net/ddv1w3yq/

Comment: then just `//div[contains(@class, 'selected')]`

Comment: in what context? like this below or just simply between the <?php ?> code?
`<?php

    function getElementsByClassName($elements, $className) {
    $matches = array();
    foreach($elements as $element) {
    if (!$element->hasAttribute('class')) {
    continue;
    }
    $classes = preg_split('/\s+/', $element->getAttribute('class'));
    if ( ! in_array($className, $classes)) {
    continue;
    }
    $matches[] = $element;
    }
    return $matches;
    }

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html_string);
    //div[contains(@class, 'selected')]

    ?>`

Comment: @Marc B I have never used path, and not sure how to place that command into my php file for execution. Any suggestions?